# Authenticate user without using factory in unit testing

Tags: laravel

I am new to unit testing. I want to authenticate a user without using Factory. I want my testing code to be simple. I don't know how to use the Factory. Here is my code :

```
public function loginVerify()
{
     $user = factory('App\User')->create();
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `$this->actingAs($user)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first thing that you have to do is follow the naming convention

Change

```
public function loginVerify()
{
     $user = factory('App\User')->create();
}
```

to

```
public function testLoginVerify()
{
     $user = factory('App\User')->create();
}
```

always use the test as a prefix for your testing function name.
and now as we look at your question, you can simply do this...

```
public function testLoginVerify()
    {
        $user_details = [
            'email' => 'demo@gmail.com', // the email of a particular user
            'password' => 'password' // the password of that user
        ];
        $this->post('/login', $user_details)->assertRedirect('/home');
    }
```

This is the very simplest way to do this.